# Implementing .Net RIA Services with Silverlight3 using only existing code/classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, service, ria

As my latest questions have stated, i am in a process of researching on Silverlight 3 and its application as a suitable RIA solution to a pre-built project a client of ours wishes to webify. And my experience in .Net and silverlight is about 3 - 4 weeks.

I have now become aware of .Net RIA Services. I require to use an existing VB class; which was created as a quick wrapper class to emulate a small piece of the client's application code. This is used as a proof of concept. It contains one function which uses the client's DLL files to return a simple data type This class has already been used successfully with Flex/Weborb combination.
I unfortunately do not have enough knowledge or experience in Silverlight/RIA Services to grasp what it is i have to do to get the file working. All the examples I find online only specify the method where you use a database as dataSource etc.

Question Then: Could you please inform me how i would go about implementing RIA Services with Silverlight 3, using existing code/classes with no DB? Or could you point me in a direction for further research on the matter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some links i have found which provides some insight in the matter. (using code snippets as reference) 
(1.) [Mark Monster - Silverlight 3 and RIA Services – The basics][1]
[1]: http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-and-ria-services-the-basics//blog/CommentView,guid,967c21b6-13a8-4385-94ba-f94893f8e347.aspx
(2.) [Mark Monster - Silverlight 3 and RIA Services – The advanced things ][2]
[2]: http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-and-ria-services-the-advanced-things//CommentView,guid,967c21b6-13a8-4385-94ba-f94893f8e347.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the garbage above. The links are:
http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-and-ria-services-the-basics/ and http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-and-ria-services-the-advanced-things/

Answer (score 2):

I think a good place to start is [Nikhil Kothari's Linq to Bing example](http://www.nikhilk.net/BLinq-Silverlight-RIAServices.aspx). In that example he creates a DomainService (which is what you need to create) that makes calls to [Bing](http://www.bing.com). You could start there to figure out how to wrap the calls to your application code instead.

Comment: Thank you. The linked examples does not provide all the needed details for someone in my position to come to a clear answer, but it is a good place to get the ball rolling with the research!