# SL3+RIA Services: what assembly is required to use InvokeOperation<Type>?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

Background: My experience in C# / Silverlight / .Net development is about 4 weeks worth.

The official documentation for .Net RIA Services July 2009 Preview, on Page 66 Section 6.2.2.2 states how one would consume the result of a call made on a function marked as [ServiceOperation]. This examples specifically uses 'InvokeOperation' (as does many examples i have found in search for an answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594384/implementing-net-ria-services-with-silverlight3-using-only-existing-code-classes)). I use Web Developer Express 2008 and when i use 'InvokeOperation' i get "The type or namespace name 'InvokeOperation' could not be found...". Please note i have Googled this but with my little knowledge i believe i am not using the correct search criteria.

My question thus:
What assembly should i reference or what should be added as 'using' in my class to enable me to use 'InvokeOperation' in my SL3+RIA Services solution?

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it: "using System.Windows.Ria.Data;"

Answer (score 1):

[ServiceOperation] (in the July CTP) got renamed to [Invoke] (in the PDC drop)
The breaking changes doc can be found here -  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3570

Comment: Thank you for the link. As i said to NotDan, as soon as i am back to working in the SL project i will be implementing/reading up on your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight 4 with the latest RIA services preview it is:

System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client

Comment: thank you. 
I haven't had the opportunity to work on the project again but intend to in the next two months. Will then check your answer in the new code. :)